# Display webform submitted data in profile page

Tags: webforms

I have created a webform with several fields. I have implemented webform registration module too. Now if the user registers, Soon after clicking register button he will need to see his profile page with the submitted values.I can use tokens for this but it's not a good idea because user should be able to edit his profile page too.
 -I have tried displaying webform submissions on view.which doesn't work here.
 -But specifically a user should see his profile page with submitted data after 
   submitting the webform
 -Please help me on this.

Comment: Thanks it works. I am looking for customized edit fields so I am trying it in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to use [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) in combination with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), you can use the webform data (as submitted via the webform) in a custom rule (to copy those webform date to the relevant profile fields). Because you have access to all ***labels*** and all ***values*** of any field of a webform, ie:

- `[data:MachineFieldName-title]` contains the **Label** of a field with machine name MachineFieldName.
- `[data:MachineFieldName-value]` contains the **Value** of a field with machine name MachineFieldName

With that, you should be able to create a custom rule with:

- Rules Event: After a webform has been submitted.
- Rules Conditions: Check the form's id (possibly with other conditions to further refine them, eg that the user is not logged in).
- Rules Action(s): Set a data value (for the appropriate profile fields, and using the values submitted via the webform).

For more details about this approach, and a prototype rule to understand the idea, refer to the answer to "[How to create a node from a Webform using rules?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199821/how-to-create-a-node-from-a-webform-using-rules/199825#199825)":

- the *1st attempt* relates to using "Entity has field" (which doesn't work for Webform)
- the *2nd attempt* explains what to do in case of Webform.

PS: I'm assuming your question is about D7 ...